# Accessing Securised Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services, https

I need to connect to a provider's web service with a Windows Form application. He gives me a certificate to access it but I have a security problem.
I have done these following steps :

1. Add certificate to personal store (on IE & Firefox)
2. Generate a proxy with the remote wsdl (no problem)
3. Use this code to call a method :

   `using (service1.MessagesService m = new service1.MessagesService())
   { 
     X509Certificate crt = new X509Certificate(@"C:\OpenSSL\bin\thecert.p12",string.Empty);
     m.ClientCertificates.Add(crt);
     var result = m.AuthoriseTransaction(aut);

   this.textBox1.AppendText(result.id.ToString());
   }`

I have the following error : 
**The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the channel SSL / TLS.**

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection isn't being authorised correctly, is the webservice over https? You may need to create a custom implementation of `CertificatePolicy`. See this [article](http://dobrzanski.net/2009/04/01/systemnetwebexception-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssltls-secure-channel/) for an example.